# How does extern template actually generate code?

Tags: c++, templates, linker

I understand the purpose of **[explicit template instantiation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation)** along with the `extern template` syntax.  The idea is to ensure that a certain template is only instantiated in one translation unit, thus potentially reducing compilation time.

But I'm confused about how this actually works in practice.  An `extern template` instructs the compiler to not *implicitly* instantiate the template in the current translation unit, with the promise that it will find the necessary template explicitly instantiated in some other translation unit at link time.  But how does the compiler avoid instantiating the template in the mean time?

For example, say we have:

```
template <class T>
struct Foo { T value; };

extern template class Foo<int>;
```

Now let's say that in the *same translation* unit we do something like:

```
Foo<int> f;
// now do lots of stuff with f
```

At this point, due to the `extern template class` statement, the compiler is not allowed to implicitly instantiate `Foo<int>`.  But then how can it even generate any code for the current translation unit?  It needs to instantiate `Foo<int>` to even know the size of `Foo<int>`, in order to even know how much to move up the stack pointer when `Foo<int> f` is declared on the stack.

Plus, `Foo<int>` may have all sorts of nested typedefs, or various member functions that are dependent on type `T`, which would be impossible to compile without implicitly instantiating `Foo<int>`.

So how does this work?  Does the compiler simply *not* generate any code involving `Foo<int>` when compiling this translation unit?  And then later at the linker phase, does it go back and splice in the necessary code into the object file after it finds an explicit instantiation of `Foo<int>` in some other translation unit?

If so, does this not also imply that a side effect of using `extern template` could be potentially increased linker times, since a lot of code generation would have to occur at link-time instead of at compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually quite straightforward. Here is a header file that defines template class `foo<T>`:

**foo.hpp**

```
#ifndef FOO_HPP
#define FOO_HPP

template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    T const & get() const {
        return _t;
    }
    void set(T const & t) {
        _t = t;
    }

private:
    T _t;
}

#endif
```

Here is a source file that explicitly instantiates the definition of class `foo<int>`:

**foo_int.cpp**

```
#include "foo.hpp"

// An explicit instantiation definition
template struct foo<int>;
```

When we compile `foo_int.cpp` to `foo_int.o`, that object file will define all
the symbols that accrue from instantiating `foo<int>`:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c foo_int.cpp

$ nm --defined-only foo_int.o
0000000000000000 W _ZN3fooIiE3setERKi
0000000000000000 W _ZNK3fooIiE3getEv
```

which with de-mangling is:

```
$ nm -C --defined-only foo_int.o
0000000000000000 W foo<int>::set(int const&)
0000000000000000 W foo<int>::get() const
```

(Note that symbols are defined [*weakly*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol)
- `W` - just as they would be as a result of implicit instantiation. Note too that
the compiler saw no need to generate any definitions at all for any of the implicitly defaulted
special member functions.)

Here is a header file that *declares* an explicit instantiation of `foo<int>` such
as we just defined in `foo_int.o`:

**foo_int.hpp**

```
#ifndef FOO_INT_HPP
#define FOO_INT_HPP

#include "foo.hpp"

// An explicit instantiation declaration
extern template struct foo<int>;

#endif
```

Here is a source file that *references* the explicit instantiation of `foo<int>`
that we declared in `foo_int.hpp`:

**make_foo_int.cpp**

```
#include "make_foo_int.hpp"

foo<int> make_foo_int(int i)
{
    foo<int> fi;
    fi.set(i);
    return fi;
}
```

and the associated header file:

**make_foo_int.hpp**

```
#ifndef MAKE_FOO_INT_HPP
#define MAKE_FOO_INT_HPP
#include "foo_int.hpp"

foo<int> make_foo_int(int i = 0);

#endif
```

Note that `make_foo_int.cpp` *is* a translation unit of the sort that puzzles
you. It `#include`s `make_foo_int.hpp`, which `#include`s `foo_int.hpp`,
which `#include`s `foo.hpp` - the template definition. And then it "does stuff" with
`foo<int>`.

When we compile `make_foo_int.cpp` to `make_foo_int.o`, that object file
will only contain *undefined references* to any symbols that accrue from
the instantiation of `foo<int>`:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c make_foo_int.cpp

$ nm -C --defined-only make_foo_int.o
0000000000000000 T make_foo_int(int)

$ nm -C --undefined-only make_foo_int.o
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U __stack_chk_fail
                 U foo<int>::set(int const&)
```

> Does the compiler simply not generate any code involving `Foo<int>` when compiling this translation unit?

The compiler generates a *call* to the *undefined external function* `foo<int>::set(int const&)`. Here is
the assembly:

**make_foo_int.s**

```
    .file   "make_foo_int.cpp"
    .text
    .globl  _Z12make_foo_inti
    .type   _Z12make_foo_inti, @function
_Z12make_foo_inti:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leaq    -20(%rbp), %rdx
    leaq    -12(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZN3fooIiE3setERKi@PLT
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rcx
    xorq    %fs:40, %rcx
    je  .L3
    call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT
.L3:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE2:
    .size   _Z12make_foo_inti, .-_Z12make_foo_inti
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1) 8.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

int which:

```
call    _ZN3fooIiE3setERKi@PLT
```

is the call to `foo<int>::set(int const&)` through the Procedure Lookup Table,
just as it might generate a call to any undefined external function that is to be
resolved at *linktime*.

Now here is a source file for a program that calls `make_foo_int` and also `foo<int>::get`:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "make_foo_int.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << make_foo_int(42).get() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If we compile `main.cpp`, the object file will also contain only *undefined references*
to symbols that accrue from the instantiation of `foo<int>`:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c main.cpp

$ nm -C --defined-only main.o | grep foo; echo Done
Done

$ nm -C --undefined-only main.o | grep foo; echo Done
                 U make_foo_int(int)
                 U foo<int>::get() const
Done
```

If we attempt to link a program using just `main.o` and `make_foo_int.o`:

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o make_foo_int.o
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `foo<int>::get() const'
/usr/bin/ld: make_foo_int.o: in function `make_foo_int(int)':
make_foo_int.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `foo<int>::set(int const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

it fails with undefined references to `foo<int>::get()` and `foo<int>::set(int const&)`.

If we relink with the addition of the necessary `foo_int.o` and ask the linker to
report the references and definitions of those symbols:

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o make_foo_int.o foo_int.o -Wl,-trace-symbol=_ZN3fooIiE3setERKi,-trace-symbol=_ZNK3fooIiE3getEv
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: reference to _ZNK3fooIiE3getEv
/usr/bin/ld: make_foo_int.o: reference to _ZN3fooIiE3setERKi
/usr/bin/ld: foo_int.o: definition of _ZNK3fooIiE3getEv
/usr/bin/ld: foo_int.o: definition of _ZN3fooIiE3setERKi
```

we succeed, and see that the linker finds a reference to `foo<int>::get()` in `main.o`,
a reference to `foo<int>::set(int const&)` in `make_foo_int.o` and
the definitions of both symbols in `foo_int.o`. `foo<int>` was instantiated
only once, in `foo_int.o`.

**Later...**

Per your comments, you still don't see how the function `make_foo_int(int)` can be
compiled without the compiler instantiating `foo<int>` if only for the purpose
of computing the size that the automatic object `foo<int> fi` that is defined
in the function will occupy on the stack.

The better to address that, I first need draw out a point that was probably insufficiently
clear before when I noted that the explicit instantiation:

```
template struct foo<int>;
```

in `foo_int.cpp` generates only definitions of the member functions *that are defined
by the template*, as shown by:

```
$ nm -C --defined-only foo_int.o
0000000000000000 W foo<int>::set(int const&)
0000000000000000 W foo<int>::get() const
```

and does not generate definitions of the implicitly defaulted special members of
the class - constructors, etc.

So, a problem very like yours is: How can the function `make_foo_int(int)` be compiled without the compiler instantiating at least the default constructor that is
executed by:

```
foo<int> fi;
```

? The answer is: it *does* instantiate that constructor, inline, just as it usually would.
(At least, it will do if the constructor is not a no-op). But it only does so *because
we did not define that constructor in the template that we explicitly instantiated
in* `foo_int.cpp`.

Let's change the template slightly too:

**foo.hpp (2)**

```
#ifndef FOO_HPP
#define FOO_HPP

template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    T const & get() const {
        return _t;
    }
    void set(T const & t) {
        _t = t;
    }

private:
    T _t = 257;  // <- Default initializer
};

#endif
```

Then recompile `make_foo_int.cpp`, saving the assembly:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c make_foo_int.cpp -save-temps
```

which now makes it obvious that the default constructor `foo<int>()`
is inlined, whereas `foo<int>::set(T const &)` is called externally:

**make_foo_int.s (2)**

```
    .file   "make_foo_int.cpp"
    .text
    .globl  _Z12make_foo_inti
    .type   _Z12make_foo_inti, @function
_Z12make_foo_inti:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    $257, -12(%rbp) ; <- Default initializer
    leaq    -20(%rbp), %rdx
    leaq    -12(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZN3fooIiE3setERKi@PLT  ; <- External call
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rcx
    xorq    %fs:40, %rcx
    je  .L3
    call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT
.L3:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE2:
    .size   _Z12make_foo_inti, .-_Z12make_foo_inti
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1) 8.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

The compiler is *able* to inline, as usual, any special member functions of
`foo<int>` that we have not defined in the template because the template
definition must be available to it whenever it sees:

```
extern template struct foo<int>;
```

as we can verify by changing `foo_int.hpp` to:

**foo_int.hpp (2)**

```
#ifndef FOO_INT_HPP
#define FOO_INT_HPP

//#include "foo.hpp"  <- Hide the template definition

template <typename T> struct foo;

// An explicit instantiation declaration
extern template struct foo<int>;

#endif
```

and attempting:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c make_foo_int.cpp -save-temps
In file included from make_foo_int.hpp:3,
                 from make_foo_int.cpp:1:
foo_int.hpp:9:24: error: explicit instantiation of ‘struct foo<int>’ before definition of template
 extern template struct foo<int>;
                        ^~~~~~~~
```

So here it is quite true to say that the compiler, as you surmised, is "at least partially instantiating `foo<int>`"
in `make_foo_int.o`. But it only instantiating a part - the default constructor - that
is not provided as an external reference by:

```
 extern template struct foo<int>;
```

and that default constructor is not so provided because we did not define it in
`template struct foo<T>`.

If we *do* define constructors in the template, say:

**foo.hpp (3)**

```
#ifndef FOO_HPP
#define FOO_HPP

template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    foo()
    : _t{257}{}
    foo(foo const & other)
    : _t{other._t}{}
    T const & get() const {
        return _t;
    }
    void set(T const & t) {
        _t = t;
    }

private:
    T _t;
};

#endif
```

then we will find them defined in `foo_int.o`:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c foo_int.cpp
$ nm -C foo_int.o
0000000000000000 W foo<int>::set(int const&)
0000000000000000 W foo<int>::foo(foo<int> const&)
0000000000000000 W foo<int>::foo()
0000000000000000 W foo<int>::foo(foo<int> const&)
0000000000000000 W foo<int>::foo()
0000000000000000 n foo<int>::foo(foo<int> const&)
0000000000000000 n foo<int>::foo()
0000000000000000 W foo<int>::get() const
```

(It looks as if they are *multiply* defined, but this an illusion and a distraction!<sup>1</sup>). And if we
recompile `make_foo_int.cpp` with `foo.hpp` **3** and our original `foo_int.hpp`:
and inspect the new assembly:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O0 -c make_foo_int.cpp -save-temps
$ mv make_foo_int.s make_foo_int.s.before   # Save that for later
$ cat make_foo_int.s.before
    .file   "make_foo_int.cpp"
    .text
    .globl  _Z12make_foo_inti
    .type   _Z12make_foo_inti, @function
_Z12make_foo_inti:
.LFB4:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -28(%rbp)
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZN3fooIiEC1Ev@PLT      ; <- External ctor call
    leaq    -28(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZN3fooIiE3setERKi@PLT  ; <- External `set` call
    nop
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rcx
    xorq    %fs:40, %rcx
    je  .L3
    call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT
.L3:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE4:
    .size   _Z12make_foo_inti, .-_Z12make_foo_inti
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1) 8.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

we see now that the default constructor `_ZN3fooIiEC1E` as well
as the `set` member function `_ZN3fooIiE3setERKi` are called externally.

Relinking our original program, it runs:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O0 -o prog main.cpp make_foo_int.cpp foo_int.cpp
$ ./prog
42
```

Which eventually preps us for the question: How can the compiler know the size
of the object `foo<int> fi` in order to compile the function `make_foo_int`, without
instantiating `foo<int>`?

As `make_foo_int.s.before` makes clear, the compiler does not need to compute the size
of any such object because, in the code that it generates, no such object exists. C++
classes and instances of classes are unknown in assembly and object code. In object
code, there are only functions and objects of fundamental integral or floating point
types whose sizes are all known from the start. A function is executed, with 0 or more arguments; it possibly acts upon objects
of those fundamental types residing in the stack, the heap or static storage, and
it (typically) returns control to the antecedent context. The C++ statement:

```
foo<int> fi;
```

in the body of `make_foo_int` does not literally compile to the placing of the object
`fi` on the stack. It compiles to the execution of a function that is the default constructor
of `foo<int>` - possibly inlined, possibly called externally; it doesn't matter - which places
an integer = 257 on its stack and finishes leaving that integer still on the stack for
its caller. The caller, as ever, does not need to know the callee's net consumption of stack.
We could redefine `template struct foo<T>` in a (rather insane) way that makes `foo<int>` a 1000
times bigger:

**foo.hpp (4)**

```
#ifndef FOO_HPP
#define FOO_HPP

template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    foo() {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
            _t[i] = 257;
        }
    }
    foo(foo const & other) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
            _t[i] = other._t[i];
        }
    }
    T const & get() const {
        return _t[999];
    }
    void set(T const & t) {
        _t[0] = t;
    }

private:
    T _t[1000];
};

#endif
```

then recompile `make_foo_int.cpp`:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O0 -c make_foo_int.cpp -save-temps
$ mv make_foo_int.s make_foo_int.s.after
```

and it makes no difference at all to the assembly of `make_foo_int.o`:

```
$ diff make_foo_int.s.before make_foo_int.s.after; echo Done
Done

$ cat make_foo_int.s.after
    .file   "make_foo_int.cpp"
    .text
    .globl  _Z12make_foo_inti
    .type   _Z12make_foo_inti, @function
_Z12make_foo_inti:
.LFB4:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -28(%rbp)
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZN3fooIiEC1Ev@PLT
    leaq    -28(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZN3fooIiE3setERKi@PLT
    nop
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rcx
    xorq    %fs:40, %rcx
    je  .L3
    call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT
.L3:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE4:
    .size   _Z12make_foo_inti, .-_Z12make_foo_inti
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1) 8.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

although it makes a difference to our program:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O0 -o prog main.cpp make_foo_int.cpp foo_int.cpp
$ ./prog
257
```

I readily recant my opening comment that "It is actually quite straightforward" :)

---

[1] The output:

```
$ nm -C foo_int.o
0000000000000000 W foo<int>::set(int const&)
0000000000000000 W foo<int>::foo(foo<int> const&)
0000000000000000 W foo<int>::foo()
0000000000000000 W foo<int>::foo(foo<int> const&)
0000000000000000 W foo<int>::foo()
0000000000000000 n foo<int>::foo(foo<int> const&)
0000000000000000 n foo<int>::foo()
0000000000000000 W foo<int>::get() const
```

seems to say that each of the constructors has *two* weakly global definitions
and is additionally defined as a `comdat` symbol! But if we disable demangling
this appearance disappears:

```
$ nm foo_int.o
0000000000000000 W _ZN3fooIiE3setERKi
0000000000000000 W _ZN3fooIiEC1ERKS0_
0000000000000000 W _ZN3fooIiEC1Ev
0000000000000000 W _ZN3fooIiEC2ERKS0_
0000000000000000 W _ZN3fooIiEC2Ev
0000000000000000 n _ZN3fooIiEC5ERKS0_
0000000000000000 n _ZN3fooIiEC5Ev
0000000000000000 W _ZNK3fooIiE3getEv
```

and we see that all the symbols are in reality distinct. The ABI mangling
maps all three of:

```
_ZN3fooIiEC1ERKS0_
_ZN3fooIiEC2ERKS0_
_ZN3fooIiEC5ERKS0_
```

to `foo<int>::foo(foo<int> const&)`, and similarly all of:

```
_ZN3fooIiEC1Ev
_ZN3fooIiEC2Ev
_ZN3fooIiEC5Ev
```

to `foo<int>::foo()`. In the GCC recipe for compiling these constructors,
the symbol variants containing `C1` and `C2` are symbols that in fact are
equivalent but are logically distinguished in the [ABI spec](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html), and the
variant with `C5` simply names a section-group in which the compiler
places the function-section in which the constructor is defined.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I understand what you're saying, in the sense that the way undefined symbols are resolved is a lot like what happens when some non-templated function is declared in a header file and uniquely defined in some other translation unit.  But what I'm still not getting is how the compiler is able to avoid at least partially instantiating `foo<int>` at all when it generates code for `make_foo_int` (even before it finds the definition of `foo<int>`).  In the generated assembly you posted, for example, at `_Z12make_foo_inti:`, I see it moving up the stack pointer to ...

Comment: make room for an instance of `foo<int>`.  But *how does it even know the size* of `foo<int>` without implicitly instantiating `foo<int>`?  At this point it hasn't found the *explicit* instantiation of `foo<int>`, (found in `foo_int.cpp`), so how does it even know `sizeof(foo<int>)`?  How can it know that without instantiating `foo<int>`, since the size could be the result of some complex type meta-program dependent on type `T`?

Comment: @Siler Hi. Answer extended. Hth.

Comment: "It is actually quite straightforward. <Ten pages of text>" :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. It looked that way because I was momentarily distracted from Brexit.